# Trying to use firebase-admin firestore onChange but deployment fails

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy my function to cloud functions but it is failing. I want to check when an item is updated in my collection.

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

admin.initializeApp({})
exports.notificationCheck = functions.firestore.document("/{collection}/{id}").onUpdate((change, context) => {
    console.log("NOTIFICATION CHECK")
    console.log(change)
    console.log(context)

})
```

Comment: "it is failing" What is going wrong? Is there an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone who might find this question. In order to use `firestore` you must also initialize the firebase project with firestore as well. Without it, it will not deploy.